# Add reponse to the Listening port created with nc -l localhost <some port>

Tags: linux, nc

How can I setup a functionality to a listening port created using the nc -l command. I want my server to respond with a pass after connection

Comment: Did you try typing something?

Comment: An example I found by searching for *web server nc*: https://jameshfisher.com/2018/12/31/how-to-make-a-webserver-with-netcat-nc/

Comment: Also `socat` can do so much more things than `nc` that the only use of `nc` I can see left is that it's shorter to type a basic command to listen to a port.

Answer (score 0):

When you say "respond with a pass" do you mean like a web server? If so, the following would work by returning valid HTTP 200. You can change echo to return whatever you need for your client.

```
while true; do { echo -e 'HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n'; } | nc -l 8080; done
```